# ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger works only on first Consume

Tags: masstransit

I have an issue regarding a .NET 6 Console App running inside Docker. I use Serilog and configure it basically on Host creation with `UseSerilog`.

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseSerilog((hostContext, configure) =>
            {
                configure.Enrich
                    .FromLogContext()
                    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Azure-Cosmos-Operation-Request-Diagnostics", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("MassTransit", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DefaultTrace,Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Direct", LogEventLevel.Error);

                configure.WriteTo.Console();
            })
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
            {
                configurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
```

In my consumers I inject `ILoggerFactory` to create ILoggers from.

First time MassTransit (current Version) consumes a message everything works fine. After that log messages are not logged to console..

Any hints what could be the problem?

Logs should be logged to console